# Bash script how to run a command remotely and then exit the remote terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kernel, remote-access

I'm trying to execute the command:

`ssh nvidia@ubuntu-ip-address "/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&"`

This works so far except that it hangs in the remote terminal when `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&"` is executed, unless i enter ctrl+c. So I'm looking for a command that, after executing the command, exits from the remote terminal and continue executing the local bash script.

thanks in advance

Comment: at the end instead of just `&` write `& disown "$!"`

Comment: @Jetchisel. Thanks for the command. this works, however it doesn't only kill the remote terminal, but also either no longer executes `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&"` or kills it

Comment: @Jetchisel. I've entered it like that. `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd&" & disown "$!"`

Comment: Like what ive said, instead of just `&`  write `& disown "$!` where `&` is separated by a space from both sides. In short only one `&` is written.

Comment: @Jetchisel `"/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd & disown "$!` if this is what you mean, it still doesn't work

Comment: If you want the job to keep going in background after the ssh connection terminates I would go nohup or disown -h. 
disown is a shell builtin so be careful should the flags be any different if the remote system is not serving you with bash.

Comment: @louigi600. thanks for the comment. The problem is not that the job is terminated in the background, but that after executing the command it stays in the remote terminal and i'm looking for a command that tells it to exit the remote terminal and continue executing the local bash script

Comment: Then maybe nohup or disown -h are what you want , they are meant to detach job from terminal otherwise you get reported you have running jobs

Comment: @louigi600. Would be glad if you show me how to write it in my case?. is this `ssh nvidia@"$x"   "/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2 svcd & disown -h"$!` what you mean?

Comment: @louigi600 and how it would look like with `nohup`

Comment: nohup command &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a command in background on a terminal, regardless of weather it be local or remotely, if you attempt to logout most systems will warn you have running jobs. One further attempt to logout and your jobs get killed as you exit.
In order to avoid this you need to detach your running jobs from terminal.
if job is already running you can

```
disown -h <jobspec ar reported by jobs>
```

If you want to run something in background and then exit leaving it running you can use nohup

```
nohup command &
```

This is certainly ok on init systems ... not sure if it works exactly like this on systems that use systemd.